# Configure PHP-cs-fixer indentation for 2 spaces rather than 4?

Tags: php, atom-editor, phpcs

Not sure if this a better question for here or SuperUser. If it belongs there feel free to move it.

I'm using [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer), and I have a unique requirement on indentations - I need two spaces rather than four. Is there a way to change this setting?

Note that I'm using atom-beautifier to run php-cs-fixer, so any solution should ideally be workable from there.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have tried. Will help community not repeat your efforts.

Comment: The  only thing I've tried on this is shutting off the indentation check on php-cs-fixer by adding `-indentation` in the "Fixers" field in Beatify's Atom settings,  which seems to have no impact in Atom's usage of the tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `PHP-CS-Fixer config file path` and set the `setIndent()` value as defined at PHP-CS-Fixer's [documentation](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/) website.

[See image for Atom package settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bdh3.png)

Set the `.php_cs` with something like this. **Note** the `->setIndent("  ")` with two spaces instead of a `\t` character.

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of PHP CS Fixer.
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *     Dariusz Rumiński <dariusz.ruminski@gmail.com>
 * This source file is subject to the MIT license that is bundled
 * with this source code in the file LICENSE.
 */

$header = <<<'EOF'
This file is part of PHP CS Fixer.
(c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
    Dariusz Rumiński <dariusz.ruminski@gmail.com>
This source file is subject to the MIT license that is bundled
with this source code in the file LICENSE.
EOF;

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
  /* ... other settings */
  ->setIndent("  ")
  /* ... other settings */
```

I am using `php-cs-fixer` plugin version 4.1.0 here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I note that `<?php return PhpCsFixer\Config::create() ->setIndent("  ");` is enough to change the indentation, though your example also shows how to combine it with other settings.

Comment: @Zachary I saved the config file you posted above into a file named `.php_cs` in the root folder of my project  so that atom-beautify for php will use those rules, but now atom-beautify does not even do anything for my php files again. No more formatting! Removing the file restores atom-beautify formatting though, but I want it to use the file so I can specify my coding style. What do I do?

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel, only change the required line(s). Specifically the `setIndent("  ")` line.

Comment: For those (like me) who'd prefer not to keep track of white space count:
```<?php return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()->setIndent(str_pad('', 2));```